# I am getting marionette error in red in the console, why?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // objects and variables instantiation
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\selenium-java-3.4.0\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

> Console: 1502197016829    geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
>   1502197016843 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:31751
>   1502197017814 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
>   1502197021151 Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette

Comment: Where is the `error`? All I see are `INFO` logs of `geckodriver` which you haven't suppressed while startup.

Comment: To be precise..., These not not errors but info shown in red colours. Just ignore and continue. Happy testing.

Comment: Hi, how can I suppress the info logs. I never found these kinda errors earlier.

Comment: They aren't really errors but they are printed in red which is generally equated with errors which adds to the confusion. They can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Download new geckodriver from below URL :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Replace new selenium server and binding jars. Download jars from below URL :-

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Update your firefox browser :-

Help -> About firefox

Run below code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// objects and variables instantiation
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\selenium-java-3.4.0\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://google.com/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for your answer. My script runs fine, I just want to know how to get rid of the error messages in the console: 1502198322242 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.18.0
1502198322257 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:16490
1502198323203 geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]

Comment: They are not errors but logs.. see the stated them as INFO not Error

Comment: http://techqa.info/programming/question/41387794/how-do-i-disable-firefox-logging-in-selenium-using-geckodriver

Comment: It's a known issue of gecko .. refer :- http://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/362